# Как автоматизировать повторную аутентификация если не подошёл пароль с первого раза с smtp_ssl?(на Gmail) (брут)

Tags: python, requests, smtp

> Как автоматизировать повторную аутентификацию, если не подошёл пароль с первого раза с `smtp_ssl`?(на >*Gmail*) (*брут*)
> для `Json` сервера брут циклит подбор пароля, и ищет пока не найдёт.
> А после запроса на gmail выдаёт вот это и код стопорится:

```
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials i2sm7866630lji.59 - gsmtp')
```

> Авторизуюсь так:

```
port = 465  # для SSL подключения
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"

context = ssl.create_default_context()

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(login, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Система безопасности Google не приветствует использование сторонних `SMTP`-клиентов, так как данный способ авторизации надёжным не считается. Поэтому пользователь, к аккаунту которого вы пытаетесь получить доступ, должен сначала [разрешить использование сторонних клиентов](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1), а если не поможет и это, [ввести логин, пароль и капчу тут](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha).

Comment: Всё так, но почта моя. Галочка на такое разрешение стоит. Подключение и манипуляции беспрепятственно производятся при помощи пайтона. Но вопрос касается цикла для дополнительных попыток входа, на сторонних сайтах он работает, а гугл брейкает при первой же попытке